# Quick way to reduce dimensions

Tags: r, optimization, correlation

I have a data frame consisting of 1200 columns. I would like to reduce this to a more manageable number, and thought of performing a cross correlation between each of the columns, and combining columns which have a r>0.9.

here is the result from dput(head(a, 20))

```
ClassTechnology..Writing.instruments = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Ink.and.lead.refills = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Printing.machinery.and.equipment = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Printing.machinery.accessories = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Printing.accessories = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Book.binding.and.sewing.equipment.and.accessories = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Printing.laboratory.equipment.and.accessories = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Lecterns.and.sound.systems.and.accessories = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ClassTechnology..Projectors.and.supplies = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.28903076, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.086521352, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Audio.presentation.and.composing.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Video.and.combination.video.and.audio.presentation.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Phone.and.video.conference.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0.0695846, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.190946024, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.086521352, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Microfilm.equipment.and.supplies = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Cameras = c(0.8608308, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.792574627, 0.25, 0.25, 0.913478648, 
0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0), ClassTechnology..Camera.accessories = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.086521352, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Photographic.processing.equipment = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Microfilm.production.equipment.and.supplies = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Darkroom.supplies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Firearms = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.740435943, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Arms.and.ammunition.accessories = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
ClassTechnology..Video.and.combination.video.and.audio.presentation.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Phone.and.video.conference.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0.0695846, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.190946024, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.086521352, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0), ClassTechnology..Microfilm.equipment.and.supplies = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ClassTechnology..Cameras = c(0.8608308, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.792574627, 0.25, 0.25, 0.913478648, 
0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0),
```

I ran the following code:

```
df=NULL
for(i in 22:ncol(a)){
  for(j in 22:ncol(a)){
    if (j<=i){next}
    df=rbind(df,cbind(colnames(a)[i],colnames(a)[j],cor(a[,i],a[,j])))
  }
}
df=as.data.frame(df)
df[,3]=as.numeric(as.character(df[,3]))
```

But it takes an incredibly long time (>2hours now), and wonder if anyone has any suggestions as to how I can improve this calculation, or a different way to reduce the dimensions

Comment: You said you want to combine columns. How do you actually want to combine them? You use `cbind` to combine `colnames` and you say you want to have a correlation value of `r>0.9`, but you don't test for it. So I am confused as to what your code is suppose to do.

Comment: See that `cor` handles `matrix` objects: just try `cor(a[,22:ncol(a)])`.

Comment: cor(a[,i],a[,j]) tests the correlation between different columns. I am making a large data frame containing the column names as well as their correlation value. I will take a look at the final data frame and merge (I guess combine is a poor choice of word) two columns whose correlation is large using UPGMA method

Comment: Do you need to preserve the columns? If not, you can use principal components analysis (PCA) to significantly reduce your inputs.

Comment: @alex I have the solution for you if could please give us part of your dataset it would make everything easier, you go `dput(head(a, 20))`, to show us the first 20 rows of your data

Comment: @Derek, here is a section of what you suggested .   ClassTechnology..Video.and.combination.video.and.audio.presentation.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ClassTechnology..Phone.and.video.conference.equipment.and.hardware.and.controllers = c(0.0695846, 
    0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.190946024, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.086521352, 
    0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @ddunn801 The problem with PCA is once I have the top x components,  how to find the columns assoc to each component?

Comment: for the sake of completeness, the above code ran in ~10hours, resulting in a df 740k, which is what I expected

Comment: @alex, that is just two variables, give me at least twenty variables and edit them in your question. so do this `head(dput(a[,1:20],20))`, the in your question, in your code, before df, add this: `a <- paste what you got from the dput function`

Comment: There are other methods of reducing dimensions, which perhaps are more suitable. Do you have some kind of target/response variable? 
Perhaps some univariate or multivariate selection technique might suite your needs or penalized regression methods like LASSO.
Perhaps calculating a correlation matrix might also be better:
cor(data)

Comment: You also seem to have some columns that don't contain information (all zeroes). Why not dump those columns?